# How to create a dynamic fragment list?

Tags: android, android-fragments, parcelable

I'm looking to create a simple pc shop ticket system. I have a new ticket activity, a list ticket activity, and an edit ticket activity. The application begins by launching the new ticket activity as shown below

[image]

To pass data between the new ticket activity and the list ticket activity I have a simple ticket object that implements parcelable as shown here:

```
import android.icu.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.Date;


public class Ticket implements Parcelable {

    private int ticket_id;
    private String name, creation_date, problem, status, fix_date;

    public Ticket(){}

    public Ticket(int ticket_id, String name, String creation_date, String problem, String status, String fix_date){
        this.ticket_id = ticket_id;
        this.name = name;
        this.creation_date = creation_date;
        this.problem = problem;
        this.status = status;
        this.fix_date = fix_date;
    }

    protected Ticket(Parcel in) {
        this.ticket_id = in.readInt();
        this.name = in.readString();
        this.creation_date = in.readString();
        this.problem = in.readString();
        this.status = in.readString();
        this.fix_date = in.readString();
    }

    public static final Creator<Ticket> CREATOR = new Creator<Ticket>() {
        @Override
        public Ticket createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Ticket(in);
        }

        @Override
        public Ticket[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Ticket[size];
        }
    };

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeInt(ticket_id);
        dest.writeString(name);
        dest.writeString(creation_date);
        dest.writeString(problem);
        dest.writeString(status);
        dest.writeString(fix_date);
    }

    public String ticketToString(){
        String temp = "";
        temp = "Ticket ID: " + ticket_id + "\nCustomer Name: " + name + "\nDate Created: " + creation_date + "\nProblem: " + problem +
                "\nStatus: " + status + "\nFix Date:" + fix_date;
        return temp;
    }

    public int getTicketId() {
        return ticket_id;
    }

    public void setTicketId(int ticket_id) {
        this.ticket_id = ticket_id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getCreationDate() {
        return creation_date;
    }

    public void setCreationDate(String creation_date) {
        this.creation_date = creation_date;
    }

    public String getProblem() {
        return problem;
    }

    public void setProblem(String problem) {
        this.problem = problem;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getFixDate() {
        return fix_date;
    }

    public void setFixDate(String fix_date) {
        this.fix_date = fix_date;
    }
}
```

My list ticket that this ticket is passed to is simply going to be a scrollable list of tickets (fragments) that I can highlight and choose to edit or delete. My question is here: I know I have to create an array list of tickets to add or delete dynamically, however how do I update and create a dynamic list of fragments, while passing data from each object in our array list of tickets? I am just coming up short trying to wrap my head around a way to complete this.

Comment: Why does it have to be fragments? Looks to me as if a RecyclerView  is what you're looking for.

Comment: I will look into this thank you